# Url redirection for custom post types - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So i have created a plugin that gets data from a API and creates posts. For example posts urls are similar to following structure .

```
https://sitesite.net/invite/username
```

About 100 posts are created this way and the only thing differs is the username. I want to redirect all
urls with `/invite` to a certain another url.

What is the best way to do this? Please consider that i'm new to wordpress.

So far i've tried some plugins like `Redirection` plugin and `SEO Redirection Premium` plugins. But i could not find a way to redirect all the urls with `/invite` in the url to another url. Both these plugins can set the source url and redirect to another url. But it's not practical for me as i have 100s of urls.

How can i redirect all my urls to another url .

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do it directly in your `.htaccess` file in the root folder of your Wordpress installation.

The following rewrite rule will redirect all pages in your `invite` folder to the same page in another folder called `newfolder`:

```
RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)$ /newfolder/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Note the `R=302` - make sure you use this for testing and only change it to a permanent 301 redirect when you are *sure* everything works!

(The .htaccess is not a Wordpress file, standard file on your web hosting. But if you’re not familiar with it, it’s a very important file to make your site work, so check back with us if you’re unsure of anything before you change it and *always make a backup before ANY changes to it*!!)

Comment: @CraZyDroiD If this answer was helpful to you, consider accepting it so that it gets marked as resolved and so that other user might find it useful if they have the same question :)